# vb.net Can an executable replace itself and how?

Tags: vb.net, updating

I want to make a simple updater for my program, but I do not want a separate executable. Is this possible?

So I check a location (ftp,http) for lets say version.txt, I compare versions. Now what? Can I overwrite my running executable and how. My program is like 4 MB ...

If it is not posible just tell me please :)

Update:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("Test.exe", "SecondTest.exe")
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("12.exe", "Test.exe")
```

This seems to work. So I rename my current executable, then put the other on its place ... Am I looking for trouble here?

Comment: youll need  separate executable :)

Comment: There are a few existing deployment tools that actually handle updating for you.  OneClick for example

Comment: Yea but I ussually try to do everything myself, becouse otherwise I just need to recode it at some point. It stop being supported or whatever.  We  build programs that will run and change for decades.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so  this  works like a charm:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("Test.exe", "oldversion.exe")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("newversion.exe", "Test.exe")
        Process.Start("test.exe")
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

So when test.exe runs, it renames itself to oldversion.exe then copies newversion to test.exe and starts it, then shuts down.

Now all I have to add is check for oldversion at every start and delete it if it exists.
The trick was to rename itself ...

Comment: If this code is running from `Test.exe` and running on Windows, I think you would get an error on either the rename or the copy due to file locking.

Comment: Try it out, It works.  And ofcourse  it is running from test.exe, that is the whole point.

Comment: This **WILL** break depending on the file system and how you install the app. One thing to remember: if you want a traditional app that install to the Program Files folder, you need administrator rights to make any changes in that folder.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this works in production.  You would probably be better to go down the route of having a launcher app in front of real exe

Comment: @lluvather, Ah!  This makes total sense to me now! There is still a lock on the executable, but it is just called `oldversion.exe` now!  The `copy` is creating a totally new file that just happens to have the same name as running  `.exe` *used to have*.  
The only issue is that you can't delete `oldversion.exe` until you restart the app.  But even that is not an issue because you restart immediately from the new file, and as you said, you can just check if it exists and delete it on startup. Brilliant!

Comment: That being said, you may still want to look into `ClickOnce`.  It does exactly what you want.... automatically update your app when it's started.  And it doesn't have any manual work for when you have a new version.